# How to prove that Cauchy-Riemann equalities hold when f(z) is complex diefferentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that a function is complex diefferentiable when Cauchy-Riemann inequalities hold.

[image: I want to prove that a function is complex diefferentiable when Cauchy-Riemann inequalities hold]

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit your post accordingly. Otherwise you may find no one interested in answering your question, and it may be closed.

Answer (score 2):

It is not sufficient for the CR-equalities to hold. The function has to be real-differentiable as a function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ as well. The easiest way to show the equivalence is to note that if we write the complex number $x+\mathrm iy$ as a vector $x+\mathrm iy=(x,y)$, then multiplication by the complex number $a+\mathrm ib$ can be written using a matrix:

$$(a+\mathrm ib)(x+\mathrm iy)=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}.$$

Remember that complex numbers are really just vectors with two components with multiplication as an additional structure. Now take the definition of complex differentiability and manipulate it until it looks like the definition of real differentiability: $f$ is complex differentiable in $z_0$ with derivative $f'(z_0)$ if

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)-f'(z_0)(z-z_0)}{\vert z-z_0\vert}=0.$$

If $f'(z_0)=a+\mathrm ib$, then $f'(z_0)(z-z_0)$ can also be written as matrix multiplication

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\ b&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x-x_0\\y-y_0\end{pmatrix}.$$

But then the above limit is just the same as the limit used to define real differentiability, and we even got the Jacobian for free. It's

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\ b&a\end{pmatrix}.$$

And since the Jacobian contains the partial derivatives of the component functions of $f(x+\mathrm iy)=\begin{pmatrix}u(x,y)\\ v(x,y)\end{pmatrix}$, you can just read the CR-equations from the Jacobian: The diagonal elements are equal, and the other two differ only by a sign. The diagonal elements are $u_x$ and $v_y$, so $u_x=v_y$. The other two are $u_y$ and $v_x$, so $u_y=-v_x$.

Comment: Thank you !! I got it all except this "It is not sufficient for the CR-equalities to hold. The function has to be real-differentiable as a function R→R as well.".Why ? The book I'm reading says : " f is complex differentiable at z_0=(x_0,y_0) if and only if u_x(x_0,y_0)=v_y(x_0,y_0) and v_x(x_0,y_0)=-u_y(x_0,y_0).What do you mean as a function from R to R? f is a function from a subset of the complex plane C to the complex plane,that's like a fuction from R^2 to R^2.

Comment: Right, it's $\mathbb R^2$. I corrected it. Anyway, the point is, $f$ might only be partially differentiable such that the equalities hold. But that's not enough. It has to be totally differentiable as well.