# Partial derivatives of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, mobius-transformation

In real algebra, if I have a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, say $f(x,y)=[u,v]$, I can calculate four different partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$. If I interpret $x$ and $y$ as spatial coordinates, I could  - for example - create two separate [quiver plots](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_quiver_plot.htm): one illustrating the partial derivatives of $u$ and one illustrating the partial derivatives of $v$.

In complex algebra, it seems like we should encounter a similar behaviour: Assume that I have $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$, and that my function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is (say) a Mobius transformation

$$M(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

whose derivative is:

$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial M(z)}{\partial z}=\frac{ad-bc}{(cz+d)^2}$$

Now here is my question: The derivative I obtain will be a single complex number. Is it possible to extract the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$? If yes, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. In general we have

$$\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dz}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\mathrm i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},$$

and the Cauchy-Riemann equations say that in addition,

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y},\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$

Together, this allows us to extract all the partial derivatives from $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dz}$ if we know its real and imaginary parts.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747973/how-to-prove-that-cauchy-riemann-equalities-hold-when-fz-is-complex-diefferent/3748011#3748011) you can find some ideas about how to obtain these equations from the definition of real and complex differentiability.